# iPhone - a UIView that behaves like a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I need to create a class that will present a UIVIew and has a some code to initialize it before it is ready to show. I need to know when the view is ready, I mean, I need something like viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, but as it is a UIVIew it lacks these protocols.

I cannot implement it as a UIViewController as I don't want to present it modal. It is really a rectangular view that needs to show on a screen side.

How do I declare this class? If the class is a UIView based I don't have the methods I mentioned.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason to not do that kind of stuff inside the `initWithFrame` method on a `UIView`? Also, you can do additional stuff on `layoutSubviews`. A view controller has `viewDidLoad` because the view is lazy loaded (from a nib or otherwise - it also has a `loadView`). It has `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` because it is **managing** the view (btw, even the view controller is managed by another view controller - these methods are called when you have the controller within a UINavigationController or UITabBarController or such classes which mange UIViewControllers. - the view itself is not really managing anything. All it knows about is how to draw itself. For that, you have `layoutSubViews`, `drawRect`, etc.

Doing some heavy stuff upon view's load will definitely kill the UI performance. You probably need to implement another kind of design pattern that will asynchrounously assign data values to the instance of your custom view - when that is done, you call `layoutSubviews` or `setNeedsDisplay` to update the view.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you described is no reason for not implementing a UIViewController. Assume you have a container view A and a subview B. Both have their own UIViewController AC and BC. Now on AC you add the View B managed by BC:

```
[self.view addSubview:BC.view];
```

Comment: No, each view doesn't need to have a view controller. A view controller manages a view that show information in a related manner. It is always composed of subviews. Subviews don't need their own controllers. A view only knows how to draw itself - and that is its sole responsibility.

Comment: In the question the reason was "as I don't want to present it modal". So I suggest to think about that "reason" carefully. Thanx for downvoting for nothin...

Comment: Well, sorry. My downvote was for the assertion that every view need to have a view controller - which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to be using `UIViewController`.

You don't just have to present them modally. You can get your view controller's view with `yourViewController.view`, and add that as a subview of whatever view you want.

If you're targeting iOS 5, there are a few new methods (such as `addChildViewController:`) designed to make doing things like this easier. You can do it on iOS 4 too though, and it'll still work.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a drawRect in youR UIView, plus an initialization flag.  Just before the view is to be displayed the drawRect will be called.  If the initialization flag isn't yet set, do your initialization and set the flag.  This will only look good if your initialization can be done quickly (no long synchronous calls).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create a class that will present a UIVIew and has a some code to initialize it before it is ready to show. I need to know when the view is ready, I mean, I need something like viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, but as it is a UIVIew it lacks these protocols.

You might want to rethink how your view is being used. It sounds like you're trying to put too much controller-like logic into your view. That's why you're wanting your view to behave like a controller.

More specifically: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you're waiting for data to load before display the view, that might actually be something to put in the controller that is calling the view.

To illustrate my point, imagine you're putting some text in a UILabel that you read from disk. The reading from disk isn't really related to the view. The view only cares what text it displays, not how it received the text. Once it's read from disk, you can create a UILabel with that text that you read. This allows the UILabel to be more flexible.

That example might not be at all related to what you're doing, but I use it as an example of the difference between a view and a controller. Anything not related with the display and drawing of the view shouldn't belong there.